# Get domain name from the email list

Tags: java

Get domain name from the email list
Hi, I have a list of email id from which i have to get the domain name.

For simple email like `sample@example.com`, I have done the code part from which I got the domain.
But for emails like `hello@in.ibm.com` (actual domain name is `ibm.com`), I am unable to get the domain.

```
String domainName = "";
String[] parts = email.split("@");
if(parts.length == 2) 
    domainName = parts[1];
```

How do I split or do a regular expression to get the domain name?

Answer (score 8):

**String#substring()** is more than fine, splitting is generating an array for nothing....(kind of waste of resources...)

define a method (is cleaner going that way...)

```
public String getEmailDomain(String someEmail)
{
    return  someEmail.substring(someEmail.indexOf("@") + 1);
}
```

Comment: I would include a check if there is really a @ in there. Or at least mention that the above will give unexpected results if @ is missing.

Comment: thanks fro you feed back. when i use this it gives exact content after @, but my requirement. when is give email id like me@in.aaronsw.com it should automatically check and should give a result as arronsw.com

Comment: "\"very.unusual.@.unusual.com\"@usual.com" this fails.

Comment: Using `String#substring()` is good only when you are learning coding - but it that case you *must* also add `null`-handling and missing-`@`-handling. If you want to have your code simple without this overhead garbage, it's better not to reinvent a wheel and use a library, such as `common-lang3` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`StringUtils.substringAfter()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), which is quite a standard, you can have it more elegant, *plus* you have `null`-handling and missing-`@`-handling for free.

```java
public String extractDomain(String email) {
    return StringUtils.substringAfter(email, "@");
}
```

> Gets the substring after the first occurrence of a separator. The separator is not returned.

You may need to add the Maven dependency, but in Spring Boot it is already included.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>   <!-- the current version as of today -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.)
```

This will give back the domain name only with no trailing suffex e.g. me@domain.com will return domain

```
(?<=@)[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+(?<=)
```

This will give back the domain and is suffix e.e me@domain.com will return domain.com or me@192.168.0.1 will return 192.168.0.1

To explain how it works

> ?<=

Positive Look behind

> @

matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character [a-zA-Z0-9.]

> +

Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

> .

matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

> ?<=

Positive Look behind

and by not giving a value to look behind null is assumed which , matches any position

For more info on Java Regex please see
[Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: the domain name is everything following the `@` and it can be even an IP address. Your solution gets `yahoo` from `name@yahoo.com` and `192` from `name@192.168.1.1`

Comment: take this email me@in.aaronsw.com. the exact domain is aaronsw when is use this split it will give all the content after @. But my result should be like aaronsw,com

Comment: @Sergey does this solution work for you and all cases that you have?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody's still wondering how to do it, here is another way, which supports input strings without '@' character:

```
private Optional<String> extractEmailDomain(String emailAddress) {
    int atIdx = emailAddress.indexOf("@");
    if (atIdx > 0) {
        return Optional.of(emailAddress.substring(atIdx + 1));
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```